# Exchanging South Korean Won for Turkish Lira

Tags: money, istanbul

Is there anywhere in Istanbul where I can exchange South Korean Won?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Central Bank of Turkey](http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/wps/wcm/connect/tcmb+tr/tcmb+tr/main+page+site+area/bugun), the following currencies are commonly exchanged in banks:

> USD, AUD, DKK, EUR, GBP, CHF, SEK, CAD, KWD, NOK, SAR, JPY, BGN, RON,
>   RUB, IRR, CNY, PKR

Therefore it is unlikely that you would be able to exchange Korean Won (KRW) anywhere in Turkey.